# How to count how many new lines I have read using fread() in c?

Tags: c

Given a size of buffer, I need to count how many new lines I have read using fread(). How to do that?

Comment: if all you have is the size of the the buffer - not possible

Comment: you can't resolve how many lines are in a buffer just from the number of bytes the buffer is.

Comment: if you're reading lines, perhaps use fgets() and save the hassle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the number of newline characters (usually `\n`) in the buffer.

Comment: Obviously to count how many _x_, code should test each `char` for _x_.  Yet a question arises when we need to count _lines_ and there is text without a trailing `'\n'`, does that count as a _line_?  For in C, it is implementation dependent if that is a _line_.

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of "previous" `char` that were `'\n'`.

If the buffer was `"abcdef"`, that would be 1 line.
If the buffer was `"abcdef\n"`, that would also be 1 line.
If the buffer was `"abcdef\ndef"`, that would be 2 lines.

```
unsigned long long linecount = 0;
int previous = '\n';
char buffer[N];
size_t len;
while ((len = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, stream)) > 0) {
  for (size_t i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if (previous == '\n') linecount++;
    previous = buffer[i];
  }
}
printf("%llu\n", linecount);
```

Comment: Very minor improvement but I would instead use `if(buffer[i]=='\n') linecount++;` in while and at the end do `if (linecount==0 && len>0) linecount++;`

Comment: @IsinAltinkaya In my experience, the `for` loop is usually more complex than the ones we have here.  In the loop body, the `linecount` is used and needs to be 1 before the first `'\n'`, hence the above posted approach.